# is it possible to personalize location permission dialog?

Tags: javascript, html, geolocation

i'm creating a script that needs to use Geolocation, i found this [HTML5 resource](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_geolocation.asp), and it shows a small window dialog asking the user for permission, something like this:

[image]

the problem is that it just shows a small window, and i want to put it in a bootstrap modal in the center of the screen, is it possible?

Comment: That dialogue is from the browser, you shouldn't have any control over it. [*MDN*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/Using_geolocation) is preferred as a javascript resource over w3schools. Try the MDN [*live result*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/Using_geolocation#Live_Result) in different browsers and you'll see a different dialogue.

Comment: Got it, so its definitely impossible?

Comment: To change the browser message, yes it is impossible. You can however show your own message before asking for geolocation, in which you say sth. like: 'To improve XYZ we are gonna ask you for your location, if that is OK with you, press Allow in the dialogue that will pop up in your browser.'

Comment: I agree with all of you. Maybe it's the best strategy as it says in this article https://iamakulov.com/notes/web-permissions/

Answer (score 1):

you can make this manually.

1. you have to add cookie for saving if user already ok.
2. if the user did not answer, you can show the dialogue with bootstrap.
3. if the user allow, you check the geolocation.
4. if the user block, you skip the geolocation.

Comment: Great! I will use localstorage instead of cookies to remember if the permissions were accepted.